# C# how to check same sign of 2 decimal values using bit?

Tags: c#

I have 2 decimal values: a and b. How do I use bit operator to check if two value is same sign?

Comment: Decimal.GetBits()[31] == OtherDecimal.GetBits()[31]..[MSDN Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.getbits.aspx)

Comment: @Sayse, after reading the documentation you've linked you'll see that `GetBits` actually returns 4 integers, not 32.

Comment: @Jodrell - I posted hastily moreover to show the msdn link, I put as a comment as I hadn't tested it :) I believe your answer came from the bottom vb example there :)

Comment: @RajeevKumar: yes, that I mean

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `Math.Sign()`. When you use `Math.Sign(x)`, if `x` is negative it returns `-1` else if its positive, the function returns `1` or when its `0` it returns `0`. So :

```
if(Math.Sign(a) == Math.Sign(b))
{
    // Code when sign matched.
}
else
{
    // Code when sign not matched.
}
```

Comment: I have one question, behind the Sign method, does it use the bit to check?

Comment: I don't know if the `Math.Sign()` method uses bit to check or not. Its a .NET inbuilt function. You may try to disassemble the function to check.

Comment: Check dnSpy. It's great decompiling tool

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean if both are positive or both are negative?

```
bool bothSameSign = (d1 >= 0 && d2 >= 0) || (d1 < 0 && d2 < 0);
```

Comment: Slightly shorter: `bool bothSameSign = ((d1 >= 0) == (d2 >= 0));`

Comment: I want to use bit to compare, may you have another solution?

Answer (score 1):

You could make,

```
static int Sign(this decimal value)
{
    return Decimal.GetBits(value)[3] & 0x8000;
}
```

and do

```
a.Sign == b.Sign;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you really need to use the bit operator for this, but if for some reason you *must* (e.g. this is a school question):

Firstly you can use [`Decimal.GetBits()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.getbits.aspx) get all the bits in the two `Decimals` to compare, as an array of 4 ints.

Then you can inspect the sign bit which is at bit 31 in the int at offset 3 in the array of ints.

```
Decimal d1 = 1;
Decimal d2 = -1;

var bits1 = Decimal.GetBits(d1);
var bits2 = Decimal.GetBits(d2);

const int signMask = 1 << 31;
const int signWord = 3;

bool sameSign = ((bits1[signWord] & signMask) == (bits2[signWord] & signMask));
```

Comment: Actually I improve performance of code, so I look up the best solution to solve the same sign(positive and negative)

Answer (score 0):

Bitwise shift is required for the sign-checking you want to accomplish:

```
if ( ( number >> sizeof(byte) * sizeof(numberType) -1 ) & 1)
{ /* < 0 */ }
else
{ /* >= 0 */ }

// you can of course use magic numbers 
// example for int: if ( ( number >> 31 ) & 1) { /* < 0 */ }
```

Problem is, you can't bitshift a `decimal`. You would have to do something like this:

```
var shiftableNumber = Int.Parse(Math.Truncate(yourDecimal));
```

I can't verify it, but I suspect it would defeat the purpose of optimizing through bitwise operators. You might aswell use the builtin `Math.Sign()` directly.